# Read a .RDS file from remote host using Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, glm

I'm hosting my first shiny app from [www.shinyapps.io](http://www.shinyapps.io). My r script uses a glm I created locally that I have stored as a .RDS file.

How can I read this file into my application directly using a free file host such as dropbox or google drive? (or another better alternative?)

```
test<-readRDS(gzcon(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/p3bk57sqvlra1ze/strModel.RDS?dl=0")))
```

however, I get the error:

```
Error in readRDS(gzcon(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/p3bk57sqvlra1ze/strModel.RDS?dl=0"))) : 
  unknown input format
```

I assume this is because the URL doesn't lead directly to the file but rather a landing page for dropbox?

That being said, I can't seem to find any free file hosting sites that have that functionality.

As always, I'm sure the solution is very obvious, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Hosted the file in a GitHub repository. From there I was able to copy the link to the raw file and placed that link in the `readRDS(gzcon(url()))` wrappers.

Answer (score 0):

Remotely reading using `readRDS()` can be disappointing. You might want to try this wrapper that saves the data set to a temporary location before reading it locally:

```r
readRDS_remote <- function(file, quiet = TRUE) {
  if (grepl("^http", file, ignore.case = TRUE)) {
    # temp location
    file_local <- file.path(tempdir(), basename(file))
    # download the data set
    download.file(file, file_local, quiet = quiet, mode = "wb")
    file <- file_local
  }
  readRDS(file)
}
```